# Could not find gem 'resque (>= 2.0) ruby' in the gems available on this machine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, resque

I am using ruby 2 installed latest version for rubygems + installed latest version for rails ie 3.2.13.

I was using delayed_job in my previous project. Now I was thinking to redis + resque. But When I am trying to install resque 2, that I got from their read me file on [Github](https://github.com/resque/resque). I am getting an error ie:

```
    Could not find gem 'resque (>= 2.0) ruby' in the gems available on this machine.
```

From Readme file. To install resque 2. Add this in your gem file and run the bundler.

```
  gem "resque", "~> 2.0"
```

As per [rubygems.org](https://rubygems.org/gems/resque) latest version is 1.24.1.

Any suggestions??

Comment: `...When I am trying to install resque 2...` Then why not show us how you're trying to install this gem (why omit details on the very thing you're requiring help with)? Show us your Gemfile. Show us the command you're running to do the install. Show us any stack trace along with the above error.

Comment: @Deefour question updated.. I was trying to install using bundler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell, the gemfile line in the readme was added in [this commit](https://github.com/resque/resque/commit/f4c622e76394e53ac25d4d42df2638ec85d15f5d) (which is a first draft of the 2.0 readme) but version 2.0 is still unreleased. The latest stable release is indeed 1.24.1.

As the readme states, you should look in the [1-x-stable branch](https://github.com/resque/resque/tree/1-x-stable) to find released versions, as the master branch contains work in progress toward version 2. Hence the readme being a little ahead of the code.

You could also try going for the very latest code by using

```
gem 'resque', :git => 'git://github.com/resque/resque.git'
```

This will (currently) install version 2.0.0.pre.1, which - it should go without saying - is **not** a final/stable release. Use with caution.